# How to number a document in this way?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I want to number a latex document so the first two pages are empty and after that on even pages I want to have page 1 of 10  on top right and on odd page I want 1 of 10 to appear on top left.

Comment: Do you use a very specific/obscure setup for your document? Because if not, you will find many answers to this question both already on TeX.SE and other 'TeX and friends' resources... In any case it would be helpful if you could show what you've tried so far in the form of an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/172164).

Comment: I have \pagestyle{empty} and at the end of title page I have written \cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}. Therefore I have now no numbers at all. But how to add page numbers after that.

Comment: @Guest  please add your code starting with `\documentclass` and finishing with  
`\end{document}`  -- click the edit button above and  copy paste the code into the box --this will help see what you have tried so far--- we can progress from there

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty: `\thispagestyle{empty}` and (re)setting the page counter to zero at the end of page 2.